# Should I worry about the battery performance when not using my Xiaomi M365 not being used for a long time?

Tags: battery, electric-vehicle, preventive-maintenance

Before SARS-CoV-2 hit the world, I use to regularly ride my electrical scooter (Xiaomi M365) for commuting. Due to the epidemic the country entered an emergency state and we are all forced to sit @ home unless **it is really necessary to go out** (requires some paperwork, food can be bought only from stores close to home etc.).

This virtually means that I cannot ride the scooter for about 2-3 months. I am wondering if I should do something special about the battery.

Based on the information I found [on the Internet](https://www.gearbest.com/blog/new-gear/the-xiaomi-m365-electric-scooter-speed-battery-life-operation-1829), the scooter has LG high security 18650 lithium batteries. I could find instructions related to the proper charging of the battery (e.g. not allowing it to be discharged too much, not allowing it to charge after reaching 100%), but I cannot find anything related to keeping the battery in good shape when the product is not used for a long time.

My intention is to charge the scooter at least once a month to ensure that the battery never discharges very much, but I am not sure if this is enough.

I vaguely remember a movie where a person was virtually riding (started the engine through a software) the scooter to discharge it and recharge it again, but I cannot seem to find it. Also, not sure if it makes sense to try this.

**Question:** Should I worry about the battery performance when not using my Xiaomi M365 not being used for a long time?

Comment: see https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/76218/10976 for some hints

Comment: @SolarMike - yes, good hint, since I also own a car that it is going to sit for about two months. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 18650 batteries are not being discharged, they will maintain their charge fairly readily. Doing what you are suggesting by ensuring they are fully charged at least once a month will maintain their health. Lithium Ion batteries do have an expected lifespan of two to three years or 300-500 charge cycles, whichever comes first. According to [this document](https://www.newark.com/pdfs/techarticles/tektronix/LIBMG.pdf):

> One charge cycle is a period of use from fully charged, to fully discharged, and fully recharged again. Use a two to three year life expectancy for batteries that do not run through complete charge cycles.

It also states:

> Lithium-Ion batteries continue to slowly discharge (self-discharge) when not in
>   use or while in storage. Routinely check the battery’s charge status.

If it is easily accessible, you could also disconnect the battery pack while not in use or being recharged. I'm sure there is a very low drain from your scooter, however, any drain is not good. Zero drain is much better.

I think your plan is spot on and should allow your batteries to remain in as good of a state as possible. No rechargeable battery will last forever (at least the ones on the market currently) and 18650's are no exception.

Comment: [This article may be of some use as well.](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries)

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the battery will void the warranty (ends in December 2020), so I will stick with check + charge. It is good to know that I do not need other tricks. Thanks.